# Expo SDK 38: Facebook install tracking and Branch.io AAID tracking are broken for Android after migration

Tags: android, react-native, expo, branch.io

After migrating from Expo SDK 37 to 38 a month ago, we have no AAID (Android Advertising ID) in the Branch.io event tracking and no Android install tracking on Facebook anymore.

The migration included the package upgrades:

- expo-branch 2.1.0 => 2.2.1
- expo-facebook 8.1.0 => 8.2.1

I have not found anything on the breaking changes that might be related to this. Also no other users describing this problem. It might have nothing to do with the SDK update and is caused by the new native release.

Any ideas?

[image: facebook dashboard]

Comment: For Branch to fetch the AAID, you'll need to include the dependency - `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:16+'` in your build.gradle file. Could you confirm if you have done that?

Comment: We are in expo managed mode. Gradle stuff is hidden...